# Query Time range between Dates using DATETIME mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a database table that has fields as such :

```
TIME(Datetime)        Update_ID
2013-11-25 05:00:14     XC3
2013-11-25 06:00:13     XC4
2013-11-25 06:00:19     XC5
2013-12-25 23:00:14     XC6
2013-12-25 24:00:00     XC7
```

So assuming i want to find a trend on the updates to know which period of the day has the a particular number of updates, what i initially think of is doing something like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(TIME) FROM  table WHERE TIME between '06:00:00' and '12:00:00'
```

But this doesn't work because i think since the date is not added with the time, a default value for date is added(some date around 1970). If, i add the beginning and enddate in my query, i am afraid it won't give me the results i need.

Comment: WHERE HOUR(TIME)...GROUP BY DAY(TIME) in case you have more than 1 day

Comment: @Mihai reply as answer and get the credit. It works, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE HOUR(TIME)...GROUP BY DAY(TIME)
```

in case you have more than 1 day

Comment: Btw, i used only HOUR(TIME) and it returned a number 29110, when i added GROUP BY DAY(TIME), i get 15 rows returned with different values, is it the sum of all these 15 rows that yields the above value ? btw, i am querying from since July, if GROUP BY presents this results based on each day, am i not suppose to have more than 15 rows returned ? Thanks

Comment: You get the all the rows with the time condition between '06:00:00' and '12:00:00' for each day in you table.You could add GROUP BY MONTH(TIME),...YEAR(TIME) if you have that need.

Comment: thank you. Just an additional question. Is there a better alternative to between ? I think between matches exactly '06:00:00' to '12:00:00'   it seems that it skips records that start with '06:00:01'. If there is no record that starts with '06:00:00' it returns zero. I thought the range should give from that starting value ?

Comment: WHERE HOUR(TIME)>= '06:00:00' AND HOUR(TIME)<= 12:00:00';

Comment: WHERE TIME(TIME) between '06:00:00' and '12:00:00'

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the problem is that when you do not specify the date, a default one is added.

You can use the [`EXTRACT` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract) to extract the time from a date, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  mytable
WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR_SECOND from TIME) between 60000 and 120000
```

Note that the time portion in the condition is specified in a different format - i.e. as numbers, without colons and quotes.

[Demo on SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0ff8/9).