# SQL Search Midnight to Midnight

Tags: mysql, sql

What would be in my where clause if I was trying to limit my results to yesterday, from midnight to midnight. I know ">= NOW() - 1 Interval Day" returns the past 24 hours, but for a daily report, and wanting to look at the report any time besides midnight itself, how can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query Time range between Dates using DATETIME mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814364/query-time-range-between-dates-using-datetime-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CURDATE()`:

```
where col >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 day) and
      col < CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/431a2/3

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1
WHERE t >= CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' 00:00:00') AS start_date,
  CONCAT(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ' 23:59:59') AS end_date;
```

That should get you the dates you want, then put the concat(...) parts into your where clause.